# nativescript code only component

Tags: nativescript

I build an app with `ns-ci`

When I build a component with XML-Based, it works, but
when I build a code only component, my genymition crashed

The xmlnamespace is like this : `xmlns:customControls="xml-declaration/mymodule"`

But when I modified it to `xmlns:customControls="xml-declaration/mymodule/mymodule.js",` it work, but throw the `error:(ui/builder/component-builder)`
 throw new

```
Error("Cannot create module " + moduleId + ". " + ex);
```

Error break at:

> **btn.on(button.Button.tapEvent, function (args) {
>               lbl.text = "Tap " + counter++;
>           });**

Anybody can provide me the complete code.

Comment: when i try to find the button.Button.tagEvent, code like this:  setInterval( function(){
            console.log("Event:", button.Button.tapEvent);
        },1000);   //console:  Event: undefined........

Answer (score -1):

My code only component is called from inside the JS; by doing a

```
var cmp = require ('mycomponent');
cmp.doWhatever();
```